# Is there a way to display data using Vuejs onChange Event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this in my Vuejs component

```
<div class="col-sm-9"> 
   <Select class="form-control" name="building" v-model="allBuild.id" @change="showBuilding($event)">
          <option v-for="b in allBuilding" :key="b.id" :value="b.id">
              {{ b.description }}
           </option>
   </Select>
</div>
```

how do i display the records coming from the api after a building is selected?

Comment: did you make a new api request when onchange is fired?? Usually when yor allBuilding change, the virtual dom is rerendered.

Comment: @StefanoMartini no i have not.. I can console log the id but i am not sure how to pass it to laravel. Do you have an idea of how i can?

Comment: there's a lot of work to do... Do you load the view with some data? Or you wait for a selection?? In the second way you need to use a ios to make a request via api, and on laravel you need to create an api and point, you can find a lot of tutorial on YouTube and is not so difficult. In the first case you need to load and pass all the data to vue, and every time you change the id, refresh and filter the all Building data. With the second case you will have a much faster page... You can olso considera to load all the data via api any time you open the page

Answer (score -1):

**Use this way**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <select class="form-control" name="building" @change="showBuilding($event)">
      <option v-for="b in allBuilding" :key="b.id" :value="b.id">
        {{ b.description }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      allBuilding: [
        { id: "1", description: "A" },
        { id: "2", description: "B" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {

    apiRequest( selectedOption ) {
      axios.get(`host.ulr/${selectedOption}`).then( res=> {
        // Something
      }).catch( err=> console.warn( "Error" , err ) )
    },

    showBuilding(e) {
        if(e.target.options.selectedIndex > -1) {
          let selectedVal = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].value;
          console.log( selectedVal)
          this.$forceUpdateapiRequest( selectedVal )

        }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, can you add some explanation as to what this is doing? What is $forceUpdateapiRequest referring to?